# Can I fetch test data from JSON file to page object file in protractor

Tags: protractor

Im working on protractor and I have created one test data (JSON) file for my project, also I'm using Page Object for my script. Sometime I need test data into my Page object file to identify the object on my screen once it is created.

I have multiple objects with same css locator, and I want to identify specific one with data i inserted using JSON. I'm using 'cssContainingText' locator to identify the object but unable to get the data directly from JSON.

Can anybody help me with solution? I don't know how to call data file (JSON) from page object file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple require statement will do to include a json file into your PageObject.

```
// The require statement will import your JSON file into the json variable
var json = require('path/to/json/file.json');

// Now you can access data from your json file as usual:
var users = json.users;   //Example 1
var data = json['data'];  //Example 2
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @Tom's answer, you can assign the test data path to `params` object of conf.js file and access it in any file just by using the variable name.

Look at below example config.js file.

```
exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  onPrepare: function () {

  },
   params: {
     testdata: require('path/to/json/file.json')
  }
}
```

And inside you pageObjects or Spec, You can access the data using `browser.params.testdata.users` or whatever the name of testdata object.